# In a local installation of edX, where are the log files and the console?

Tags: console, edx

I'm getting errors from the Studio page, and I want to see what the errors are on the server side.

I also see mention here https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack#signing-up-a-new-user-activation-message-problems that there is a console.  When logged into the edX VM, how do I monitor this console?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting errors from the Studio page, and I want to see what the errors are on the server side

Try looking in /edx/var/log

> When logged into the edX VM, how do I monitor this console?

Those are instructions for devstack, if you are using devstack you would be running runserver in the console which is where those messages would appear.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting errors from the Studio page, and I want to see what the errors are on the server side.

For Studio errors look in /edx/var/log/cms/edx.log inside your virtual box VM.

> When logged into the edX VM, how do I monitor this console?

To run and monitor the console, perform the following steps starting from your installed vagrant directory (the one with the Vagrantfile) on your host:

First, ssh into the VM:

```
vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '14.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

*******************************************************************
*   ___                         _ __  __                          *
*  / _ \ _ __ ___ _ _    ___ __| |\ \/ /                          *
* | |_| | '_ \ -_) ' \  / -_) _` | >  <                           *
*  \___/| .__/___|_|_|  \___\__,_|/_/\_\                          *
*       |_|                                                       *
*                                                                 *
*  Instructions and troubleshooting:                              *
*  https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack  *
*******************************************************************
Last login: Tue May 12 22:21:14 2015 from 10.0.2.2
```

Then become the edxapp user:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo su edxapp -s /bin/bash
edxapp@precise64:~/edx-platform$ cd ~
edxapp@precise64:~$ source edxapp_env
```

Start the Studio application (--fast is optional):

```
edxapp@precise64:~$ cd edx-platform/
edxapp@precise64:~/edx-platform$ paver devstack --fast studio
---> pavelib.servers.devstack
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
Enter CTL-C to end
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.18, using settings 'cms.envs.devstack'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

In this example, the first line of the console output is:

```
---> pavelib.servers.devstack
```